# Docker container - different behaviour on Win and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers, pipeline

I have docker container, I run it and after some time it has to execute this line

```
$(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | sed -e 's/-e none//g')
```

Now the weird thing is - when I run it on my local machine (Windows) it passes and writes the `Login Succeeded`

When I run it on the Linux-Ami agent, everything works correctly, but when it gets to this line it outputs

`/app/ops/release/docker-run.sh: 51: /app/ops/release/docker-run.sh: aws: not found`

I am confused as I am using docker to actually have the same environment no matter when I execute it. The only non-docker part is when I build the image and run it (and in that part I understand if there are some differences), but then everything else runs in container based on same Dockerfile in both environments.

The only real difference can be the environment variables that are passed into container on start.

Any idea?

Part of the Dockerfile for building image for this container is `RUN pip install --upgrade awscli`

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

I passed all environment variables into the container -> on linux I passed variables such as `PATH` and destroy auto-finding the correct `bin` folder.

If I call it as `/usr/local/bin/aws` it works on both system. After passing only relevant environment variables then the `aws` works out of the box.